# spark saveAsTable permissions

Tags: apache-spark

When a spark program writes a table using DataFrame.saveAsTable, it creates the HDFS file permissions as the user who the job is running as. This is as expected, however, I would like to be able to set write permissions to a larger group so that the table may be manipulated manually with a command such as "DROP TABLE" or updated by other users.

How can I set the group HDFS permissions during the table write in spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing permission while running `saveAsTable` is not possible. you can use hadoop-client library to change the hdfs path permission as shown below.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import java.net.URI

val uri = new URI("hdfs://hdfs-namenode:8080/target/path")
val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(uri, new Configuration())
fileSystem.setPermission(new Path(uri), new FsPermission(777: Short))
```

The hadoop client package can be added to the project using the below code in the sbt build file.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.2"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any alternative, e.g. modify default permissions used for HDFS file writes through hive to always write as the same user? Spark seems to ignore both hive.warehouse.subdir.inherit.perms and hive.server2.enable.doas.